# Relacionamentos com Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou fazendo um pequeno blog em Ruby on Rails, mas estou com problemas na parte dos comentários.

Em `controllers/posts/comments_controller.rb` eu tenho o seguinte:

```
class Posts::CommentsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :require_authentication

def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.student_id = current_student.id

    if @comment.save
        redirect_to @post
    end
end

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
end

end
```

Em `views/posts/_comment.html.erb` eu tenho:

```
<% if student_signed_in? %>
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :comment %>
        <%= f.text_area :comment %>
    </p>
    <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

E em `views/posts/show.html.erb` eu tenho:

```
<%= render 'comment' %>
```

Duas coisas estão dando erradas: eu não sou redirecionado para o post quando crio um comentário, mas sim para `posts/:post_id/comments` e outro problema é que eu não consigo criar comentários! Eu simplesmente sou redirecionado para `posts/:post_id/comments`.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 5):

No seu caso, se tratando de um comentário de post, o comentário deve pertencer ao post e post deve ter muitos comentários. Primeiramente, você precisa ter no seu model post.rb:

```
# post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

e em comment.rb:

```
# comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Este relacionamento precisa estar tabela comments que possui a coluna post_id. Este post_id precisa estar referenciado nos parâmetros permitidos. Assim:

```
# comments_controller.rb
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id)
end
```

Tendo isso configurado, no método create de comments_controller.rb temos:

```
# comments_controller.rb
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) # pega post_id para encontrar o post que comentário será relacionado
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params) # cria o comentário conforme os parâmetros passados

  redirect_to post_path(@post) # redireciona para o post definido pelo id na variável @post
end
```

Neste caso, não vejo necessidade em usar o método respond_to para renderização por se tratar de um cometário. Normalmente, isso se aplica quando quer mostrar o post com/sem seus comentários.

Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: 0lá. Para melhor organização do código, o comments_controller em uma pasta posts/, por isso o nome da class é Posts::CommentsController. Mesmo assim, eu preciso colocar has_many e belongs_to?

Comment: Precisa porque esse é o relacionamento feito no banco de dados. Sem isso no model não vai funcionar.